# Need help with proving if an equality is true or not

Tags: calculus, inequality

So I have this inequality and have to prove it or disprove it.

$$k^c + \sqrt{ k^k }{2^{2-k}} - (k+1)^c \leq 0$$

For $k \geq 1$ and $c>0$.

Comment: Take $k=c=1$. Then it is wrong.

Comment: Is $c$ an integer? Is $k$ an integer? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Where did you encounter this?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  Please include what you have tried and any thoughts on what you might use to solve the problem.

Comment: found it in a book. i have another one. sqrt(k)*k^c + (2*sqrt(k+1)-1) * sqrt(k^k )/2^(k-1)  -sqrt(k+1)*(k+1)^c≤0. k>=1, c>0 both real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=1$:

your statement becomes
$$1+2-2^c \leq 0$$

$$3 \leq 2^c$$

Now, let $c=1$. we get a contradiction.